# Installed Gitblit and git clone error with ssh

Tags: java, git, ssh, gitblit, qnap

I have succeeded in running [Gitblit](http://www.gitblit.com) in [QNAP TS-221](http://www.qnap.com)(CPU marvell(ARM)).

And then, I created git repository, admin account,id_rsa.pub,etc.

Finaly, I execute "git clone ssh://admin@192.168.0.3:29418/doc.git" command , there is an exception occurrence

```
Received disconnect from 192.168.0.3 port 29418:9: sendKexInit() no resolved
signatures available
Disconnected from 192.168.0.3 port 29418
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

and tomcat's log

```
org.apache.sshd.common.SshException: sendKexInit() no resolved signatures available at org.apache.sshd.common.session.AbstractSession.sendKexInit(AbstractSession.java:1432) at
org.apache.sshd.server.session.ServerSessionImpl.readIdentification(ServerSessionImpl.java:197) at org.apache.sshd.common.session.AbstractSession.messageReceived(AbstractSession.java:325) at 
org.apache.sshd.common.session.AbstractSessionIoHandler.messageReceived(AbstractSessionIoHandler.java:57) at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session$2.onCompleted(Nio2Session.java:220) at 
org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session$2.onCompleted(Nio2Session.java:212) at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2CompletionHandler$1.run(Nio2CompletionHandler.java:34) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2CompletionHandler.completed(Nio2CompletionHandler.java:31) at 
sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126) at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeDirect(Invoker.java:157) at 
sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:553) at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:276) at 
sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:297) at java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel.read(AsynchronousSocketChannel.java:420) at 
org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session.doReadCycle(Nio2Session.java:247) at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session.doReadCycle(Nio2Session.java:243) at 
org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session.startReading(Nio2Session.java:198) at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session.startReading(Nio2Session.java:194) at 
org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session.startReading(Nio2Session.java:190) at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session.startReading(Nio2Session.java:186) at 
org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Session.startReading(Nio2Session.java:182) at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Acceptor$AcceptCompletionHandler.onCompleted(Nio2Acceptor.java:149) at 
org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Acceptor$AcceptCompletionHandler.onCompleted(Nio2Acceptor.java:128) at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2CompletionHandler$1.run(Nio2CompletionHandler.java:34) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2CompletionHandler.completed(Nio2CompletionHandler.java:31) at 
sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126) at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218) at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I installed the same softwares in Ubuntu14.04 , everything is ok!

Thanks for all you help!